# How to make the flex box cover the entire page as required?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I have been trying to set the .flex-container to cover entire page below the horizontal rule, but when I resize the window, in around 1200px width, the flex box container is not going all the way down. I am fine with the buttons coming as a column when viewing on a small screen, as already happening.

what I want to happen

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: #06283D;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.heading {
  color: #1894E7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 3.6em;
  margin: 5%;
}


.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #256D85;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #06283D;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  }

.flex-container>button {
  background-color: #DFF6FF;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 6%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition-duration:0.3s;

}
.flex-container>button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  transition-duration:0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1086px){
  .flex-container>button{
    margin: 7%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Papers</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Loren ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <hr style="margin:0;position: relative;left:-15px;width:100%;height:0.5px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:black;opacity:0.5">


      <div class="flex-container">
        <button>1Year</button>
        <button>2Year</button>
        <button>3Year</button>
        <button>4Year</button>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the styling of the flex-container:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #256D85;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #06283D;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Then it will certainly cover the whole page.

Comment: It doesn't help, if bottom: 0 then the whole container moves down instead of starting right from the horizontal rule, and if we reduce screen size further, we get something unexpected

Comment: @VatsalyaSharma Did you notice the `position: absolute;`? But I agree, it is far from perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the point of using `position: absolute`, so if that's not requisite, you get rid of `position:absolute` and instead change it to `height: 100vh`, it'll stretch to be equal to the vertical height of the viewport. If 100vh is too tall, you can change it accordingly.

Another option would be to give the body a dynamic height like 100vh (which will force the entire page to be exactly the height of the viewport) and add `overflow:hidden` to the body. Note, in this scenario if any of the buttons wrap and force the parent div to be any larger, you won't be able to scroll to them.

A final option would be to wrap the whole thing in a wrapper div and then make that div `display: flex;` see here: https://jsfiddle.net/slingtruchoice/jc03nft2/

Position absolute can be really annoying to work with, in my humble opinion. I avoid it when possible, simply because it affects the way other elements (siblings in particular, ie divs that come after your .flex-container div) interact with it. The use cases for position: absolute would be if you're trying to overlay an object on top of another object, or move it to a non-standard position within a parent container. If you look at the jsfiddle link at the bottom, i've included an example of ways to use position:absolute at the top.

```css
body {
  background-color: #06283D;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.heading {
  color: #1894E7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 3.6em;
  margin: 5%;
}


.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #256D85;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #06283D;
  height: 100vh; /* here's the change*/
}

.flex-container>button {
  background-color: #DFF6FF;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 6%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;

}

.flex-container>button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1086px) {
  .flex-container>button {
    margin: 7%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
    <button>Click Me!</button>
    <button>Click Me!</button>
    <button>Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/slingtruchoice/56e0sj4k/

Comment: Thanks it is working but now the flexbox is causing page to extend as it requires 100vh height, causing unwanted scroll

Comment: @VatsalyaSharma, you can change the ```height: 100vh``` property to fit your desired height for .flex-container. Another option would be to give the ```body``` a height of 100vh (or another height) and add ```overflow:hidden;``` to the css. You could also wrap everything in a wrapper div and give it display: flex, and give the header and flexbox different flex-basis values to each child. Edited response above.

Comment: Well I tried it but wasn't getting the required result so I began from scratch again and this time it worked. Have a look at index.html and css file in this repo https://github.com/vatsalya1102/Papers

Comment: @VatsalyaSharma great to hear! Happy to see that flex is doing what you need it to do!